# Obfuscate JPG by bit-toggle - reading performance on Android

Tags: android, performance, image-processing

**Abstract:**

- reading images from file
- with toggled bits to make unusable for preview tools
- cant use encryption, to much power needed
- can I either optimize the code below, or is there a better approach

**Longer description:**

I am trying to improve my code, maybe you got some ideas or improvements for the following situation. Please be aware that I neither try to beat the CIA, nor care much if somebody "brakes" the encryption.

The background is simple: My app loads a bunch of images from a server into a folder on the SD card. **I do NOT want the images to be simple JPG files**, because in this case the media indexer would list them in the library, and a user could simply copy the whole folder to his harddrive.

The obvious way to go is encryption. But a full blown AES or other encryption does not make sense, for two reasons: I would have to store the passkey in the app, so anyone could get the key with some effort anyway. And **the price for decrypting images on the fly is way too high** (we are talking about e.g. a gallery with 30 200kB pictures).

So I decided to **toggle some bits in the image**. This makes the format unreadable for image tools (or previews), but is pretty easy undone when reading the images. For "encrypting" I use some C# tool, the "decrypt" lines are the following ones:

```
public class CustomInputStream extends InputStream {
    private String _fileName;
    private BufferedInputStream _stream;


    public CustomInputStream(String fileName) {
        _fileName = fileName;
    }

    public void Open() throws IOException {
        int len = (int) new File(_fileName).length();
        _stream = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(_fileName), len);
    }


    @Override
    public int read() throws IOException {
        int value = _stream.read() ^ (1 << 7);
        return value;
    }


    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {
        _stream.close();

    }

}
```

I tried overwriting the other methods (read with more then one byte) too, but this kills the BitmapFactory - not sure why, maybe I did something wrong. Here is the code for the image bitmap creation:

```
Bitmap bitmap = null;
try {
    InputStream i = CryptoProvider.GetInstance().GetDecoderStream(path);
    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(i);
    i.close();
} catch (Exception e1) {
    _logger.Error("Cant load image " + path + " ERROR " + e1);
}
if (bitmap == null) {
    _logger.Error("Image is NULL for path " + path);
}
return bitmap;
```

Do you have any feedback on the chosen approach? Any way to optimize it, or a completely different approach for Android devices?

Comment: honestly if all you need to do in make sure its not indexed store it without a file extension. Otherwise force the app to download them from an external server each time.

Comment: Sorry, not possible. Total sum of download is 150MB, over 1000 pictures. And no file extension is to simple, a normal user would just have to do a bulk rename - ok, only 5% know this, but still. A bit toggle on the images makes them unusable for 99.99% of the users - programmers can figure it out, but they can anyway by decompiling the app - I just try to find the right "copyright protection level" - it sucks, but you have to earn some money :-)

Comment: Maybe your problem is the over 150MB of pictures... that is a real lot

Comment: Thats the purpose of the app :-) Its a dictonary with over 1000 high quality pictures, which is supposed to work offline. If it would only be a few I would not care if anybody copies them. But we pay for the pictures, so we need to at least protect them a little bit - not like Fort Knox - but a simple copy and rename should not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try XORing the bytestream with the output of a fast PRNG. Just use a different seed for each file and you're done.

note: As already noted in the question, such methods are trivial to bypass.

Comment: I dont understand the approach. Would this speed up things? Or make it harder to "crack" - Toggling always the first bit maybe less secure, but I think faster. As already said, if you want to beat this encryption, its a piece of cake. But I am talking about somebody which only knows "files" and not "bytes" - so if I brake his JPG somehow (toggling bit 1 on every byte) its enough.

Comment: Just one idea, maybe its enough to toggle only the first bit of the first 10 bytes, afterwards leaving them as is. Might speed it up, but the counter check may be more expensive then a simple "toggle all".

Comment: Went with the FF D8 approach. Works nicely, just reading the whole image as byte array, correcting the two broken bytes, and hand it over to BitmapFactory. Thanks for the idea..